# How to explain the fast motion of the Starlink satellite in this video?

Tags: identify-this-object, starlink, astronomy

My friend in Łódź sent me this video today:

https://i.imgur.com/EmpNzfs.mp4

This was observed in Widzew district, at 20:42 Warsaw time. He has two questions:

1. given that it looks like it's Starlink satellite deployment, why is one of the lights going so fast?
2. what could be the other light that isn't moving?

Comment: What makes you think it's Starlink?

Answer (score 2):

The Sun is setting in Warsaw at around 7:12 PM right now. This was taken about an hour and a half after sunset then. I'm pretty sure these are too high in the sky for them to be satellites with it this late. Satellites are only really visible during dawn and dusk and about 2 hours after. This is because satellites are nowhere near bright enough to be seen with the naked eye without the sun reflecting off of them.

If I had to make a guess I'd say they are both some sort of aircraft potentially drones or helicopters. Probably some sort of object that's able to hover in place for an extended period. I'd also rule out any sort of planets or stars because they are way too bright. Especially with all the light pollution present.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** It's probably *a pair of small drones with LEDs* or *a satellite flare* next to something unidentified.

---

To me this could look like a pair of small drones with LEDs. One remains static and the other slowly rotates so that it appears to brighten and dim as it passes the other.

Some have [Lambertian distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law) (see more in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/450922/102305)) but with the plastic lenses it can be more focused and so a smaller rotation can produce the same light curve.

It looks like the object that brightens then dims through a huge range (from saturation to invisible) does so over only about 10 degrees or less. There's no way to do both like that just from Sun and Earth's shadow.

*It could be a [satellite flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare) though!* See questions and answers here tagged [satellite-flare](/questions/tagged/satellite-flare) for more on that.

It does look a lot like what a flare should look like. I don't think Starlink satellites have the capacity to flare this brightly, but perhaps some do.

If it's really a satellite, then it's probably a flare.